# Javascript / jQuery image zoom plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, zooming

I need to display an image in a fixed size div.
Under the div must be some control, like a cursor bar, which sets the resolution of the displayed image.
I don't mind much writing the thing, but I thought it might already exist. How come I can't find such a thing ?

(I am not interested in things like jQZoom nor zoomimage which do not let the user choose dynamically the display resolution.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this question has now been seen more than 1k times, I add my solution to it. Feel free to copy and adapt.

The solution involves jQuery UI slider plugin. Mainly we create a div with fixed size, overflow:scroll, containing a img tag, and we add a slider under it. The slider 'change' event is bound to a rescale of the img@width/@height attributes.

Here is an excerpt of what we did :

**HTML**

```
    <div id="pictureFilePreview">
        <img id="pictureFilePreviewImg" src="style/images/spacer.gif"/>
    </div>
    <div id="pictureSlider"/>
```

**JS**

```
$('#pictureFilePreview').css('overflow','scroll');
$('#pictureFilePreviewImg')
    .attr("src", "http://url.of.the.image")
    .css("display","block")
    .bind("load", function(){ //wait for complete load of the image
        // Slider  
        var initHeight = parseInt($('#pictureFilePreviewImg').attr("height"));  
        var initWidth = parseInt($('#pictureFilePreviewImg').attr("width"));  
        if ($('#pictureFilePreview').width() < initWidth 
            || $('#pictureFilePreview').height() < initHeight) {                

            var deltaW = $('#pictureFilePreview').width() - initWidth;  
            var deltaH = $('#pictureFilePreview').height() - initHeight;
            var ratio = 0;
            if (deltaW < deltaH) {
                ratio = ($('#pictureFilePreview').width() / initWidth) * 100;
            } else {
                ratio = ($('#pictureFilePreview').height() / initHeight) * 100;
            }
            $('#pictureSlider').slider({  
                range: false,
                min : ratio,
                values: [100],
                change: function(event, ui) {  
                    var newHeight = ((initHeight) * ui.value / 100);  
                    var newWidth = ((initWidth) * ui.value / 100); 
                    $('#pictureFilePreviewImg').attr("height",newHeight);  
                    $('#pictureFilePreviewImg').attr("width",newWidth);  
                    $('#pictureFilePreview').css('overflow',ui.value === 0?'visible':'scroll');  
                }  
            }); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's worth the effort for you, but there's some terrific libraries that do exactly this in Cappuccino.  The tutorial walkthrough shows you how to build an app that zooms and rotates images:

[Scrapbook tutorial](http://cappuccino.org/learn/tutorials/scrapbook-tutorial-1/)